# Replace an input hidden value before submitting a form with some value fetched via Ajax

Tags: javascript

I have the following submit handler which should lookup for some value based on the user input (key) and update an hidden field with the fetched value, before submitting the form.

```
$('#my_form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "lookup.php?key=" + $('#key').val(),", // Read one of the user input and lookup
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
     console.log(data); // Shows the expected result
     $('#my_form').find('input[name="xxx"]').val(data); // Substitute the hidden xxx with the fetched data
     return true;
    }
  });
  console.log($('#my_form').find('input[name="xxx"]')); // Still the old value here
  return true;
});
```

Unfortunately, the final submitted form seems to contain the old value, as shown in the console.log. Given I'm very new to JS, I guess I'm missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make an asynchronous call, and your `console.log` is called before you receive a result from ajax call. So your input changed, but not when you are outputting it. You can add  `async:false` option to `$.ajax`, and check `console.log` - it will output the changed value

Comment: I'm aware the Ajax request is asynchronous. I guess I was looking for a way to invert this behaviour and the async parameter is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hej the ajax call is async so it will not return and update your code before you submit the form.

What you need to do is to withhold submitting the form and submit it when the
ajax call returns.

!Update to prevent inf loop

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(e) {
 if($(this).find('input[name="xxx"]').val() === "") { // assuming its the default
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "lookup.php?key=" + $('#key').val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
     $('#my_form')
      .find('input[name="xxx"]').val(data).end()
      .submit();
    }
  });
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
});
```

Comment: won't it go in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(e, skipAjax) {
    if(typeof(skipAjax) == 'undefined') {
        $.ajax({
            url: "lookup.php?key=" + $('#key').val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            $('#my_form')
               .find('input[name="xxx"]').val(data).end()
               .submit('skipAjax');
            }
        });
        return false;
    } else {
         return true;
    }
});
```